# Get the last element of a user defined object array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, quantitative-finance

```
pricePH = ta.pivothigh(10, 10)

type Candle
    int index
    float pivotHigh 
    float pivotLow

var CandleArray = array.new<Candle>(0)

if pricePH
    ph = Candle.new(time[10], high[10], low[10])
    array.push(CandleArray, ph)

var Candle xyz = na

if array.size(CandleArray) > 0
    xyz := array.get(CandleArray, array.size(CandleArray) - 1)
```

// It give the following error: Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'series'='xyz'. An argument of 'Candle' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.

```
plot(xyz, display = display.status_line)
```

//// Currently the only method to access the elements of the array is through a for-in loop

```
for newPH in CandleArray
    label.new(newPH.index, newPH.pivotHigh, str.tostring(newPH.pivotHigh), xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_label_down, color=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xyz is a Candle type, you must tell your script which float to use.
For example :

```
plot(xyz.pivotHigh, display = display.status_line)
```

Here is the complete working script (tested on EUR/USD) :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(close)
type Candle
    int  index
    float pivotHigh 
    float pivotLow

var CandleArray = array.new<Candle>(0)

if true
    ph = Candle.new(time[10], high[10], low[10])
    array.push(CandleArray, ph)

xyz = array.last(CandleArray)
plot(xyz.pivotHigh, display = display.status_line)
```

Comment: I get the error `Error on bar 0: Cannot access the 'Candle.pivotHigh' field of undefined object. The object is 'na'.`

Comment: @x945 I update my answer, try the complete working script alone to see it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Your answer was somewhat helpful but it is getting the values for every bar whereas the question was asking to register the values for every Pivot High.